# How do I enable continuous deployment of Node.js applications to Amazon EC2?

Tags: node.js, deployment, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cloud

I am a node.js developer. I have used Heroku and Joyent's no.de platform before .

For both of these platforms , the deployment used to be simple

```
git push heroku master ( Heroku )

git push joyent master ( Joyent's node)
```

The above commands used to do the magic . They enabled me to push the code from my local machine to the cloud server, deploy it and automatically restart the server .

Now I am planning to use Amazon AWS as its more configurable to my needs. How do I setup a similar thing on Amazon EC2 for continuos deployment ?

I am using an Ubuntu AMI.

Is there any tool that help me achieve this ? 
If there are any resources/tutorials  that might help me - please let me know.

Thanks !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That auto-deploy mechanism is implemented with [Git Hooks](http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html). The most likely hook used is `post-update`.

It's a simple bash script that is executed on a `git push`; put one in a git repository on your EC2 server including the code to re-run NPM (if needed) and restart your code.

That's should do it. :)

Answer (score 4):

Use [roco](https://github.com/1602/roco) - deployment solution inspired by capistrano, working great with express/railwayjs + git + upstart. If you have another env feel free to customize it using Roco.coffee

It also can be simply configured with `post-update` hook to work exacty as in heroku and joyent.

Here is tiny tutorial for this tool: http://node-js.ru/4-deploy-with-roco

Answer (score 2):

Check out [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/)

It lets you deploy your application to an amazon ec2 instance by running:

```
git aws.push --environment testing
// or
git aws.push --environment production
```

The [documentation page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs.html) contains a lot of quality information to get your started!